# Yii2 custom pagination view

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, pagination, yii2

**Hello everybody. 
I need to do a custom pagination for the GridView.**
In GridView I used:

```
'pager' => [
        'prevPageLabel' => '<div style="border: none" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></div>',
        'nextPageLabel' => '<div style="border: none" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></div>',
        'maxButtonCount' => 0,
]
```

As a result, I get two arrows and then I can style them:

[image]

**Question: How to put your own content between these arrows?**

For example, I can get count of page: `<?= $dataProvider->totalCount; ?>` and I want to put this total count of pages between the arrows of pagination. **How can I do this?**
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend LinkPager class, override [renderPageButtons()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/LinkPager.php#L171) to generate whatever content you like and then use this extended class in GridView configuration:

```
'pager' => [
    'class' => 'new\extended\LinkPager'
]
```